# How to silence "[Violation] setTimeout handler took <N> ms" in Google Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

(I have viewed other questions on StackOverflow and their answer is: make your JS code run faster.)

When I write some experimental program or benchmark what's the fastest way to do something in JS on Google Chrome using benchmark.js, I get:

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 77ms              lodash.js
```

or

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took <N>ms             lodash.js
```

So it is not even my code but in `lodash.js`, and in some cases, I don't really care because I am doing a loop for 10,000 times just for the purpose of benchmarking.

So is there a way to silence this?  Just for my own peace of mind, or that if I am demo'ing to some people, and I hope to make the error / warning messages to show up the least amount possible.